# What dua's and dhikrs are recommended to recite when going to sleep?

Tags: dua, reference-request, adab

I'd like to know about what kinds of du'a and dhikr are recommended to perform when one wants to go to sleep?

I'm sure there's a whole lot, I don't expect a full list, but a refrenced and sourced one.

And if there's an order I'd also like to know about that!

Comment: If you are on android you can try the below app. It is a good list of azkar before sleeping along with excellent audio for listening & memorizing the duas: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ahmed.islambeforesleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read that the Prophet(peace be upon him) used to recite Ayatul kursi:

> Prophet (ﷺ) said, “By reciting it (Ayat- ul-Kursi), there will be a guardian appointed over you from Allah who will protect you during the night, and Satan will not be able to come near you until morning” [Al-Bukhari]

Comment: Would you mind adding the links?